# Edit FLV and mute audio on given frames

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio, flv

I've been given a avi file that I've turned into an flv and now need to create two versions of that flv, one with all the audio and one with a small section of the audio removed (its narrated and we need to remove the mentioning of a specific item).

I know I can import an flv into the flash timeline but am not sure how to kill the sound for a given portion of frames,

Was considering redoing the flv as two separate flv's, one with video and one with audio and then putting them into the timeline and cutting the audio up, but I would love a cleaner way, preferably with ActionScript

Thanks in advance,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SoundMixer.stopAll();`

Fire the command when you need to stop every sound.

Visit this [link](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html) for more info about SoundMixer class

---

If you are looking for pause play, then I found this.

```
private function setVolume(volume:Number):void 
{ 
var transform:SoundTransform = channel.soundTransform; 
transform.volume = volume; 
channel.soundTransform = transform; 
}
```

Call the function as `setVolume(0)` or `setVolume(100)`

---

Hope that helps you out.